# How to find 10th digit of $\sum_{k=1}^{49} k!$

Tags: summation, factorial

How to find the tenth digit (from the right) of $\sum_{k=1}^{49} (k!)$ analytically.

The worst possible method would be to actually sum each individual number which would yield a number of order $10^{62}$ . So this method is almost impossible.

Also I am new user so please point out if I am wrong somewhere.

*Note: The tenth digit and not the 10's digit.*

Comment: 10th digit from left or right?

Comment: Fairly soon, factorials end in two zeros.  After that, the tens digit doesn't change.

Comment: Calculating it up to $9!$ should do the job.

Comment: @Arashium from the right

Comment: Do you think it is possible?

Comment: @Sayan98 10th digist or tens digit?

Comment: $\sum_{k=1}^{49} k! = 620960027832821612639424806694551108812720525606160920420940313$, so the answer is $0$.  Far from being "almost impossible", this is a calculation that can be done by hand with some time investment.  Easier, but only a _little_ easier, is working modulo $10^{10}$.

Comment: I don't think the big bolded words in the question are necessary.  Everybody knows the difference between tens and tenth, but the original question actually read "tens", which is why there was confusion.

Comment: @Slade My bad with the typo.

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid big numbers by doing the multiplies $\bmod {10^{10}}$ and just add them up.

Comment: You need up to $44!$ because $45$ gives the tenth 5.

Comment: @Michael: that is correct.  Toward the end you only have a few digits to worry about as there are lots of zeros.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** The answer was posted before the edit.

The factorials starting from $10!$ onwards to $49!$ end with 2 zeroes. So they have no contribution to tens' digit.

Hence we can sum easily $$1!+2!+3!+4!+5!+6!+7!+8!+9!$$ $$=1+2+6+24+120+720+5040+40320+362880$$

The last $2$ digits of the sum add up to $13$.

Hence tens' digit is $1$.